# Execute PROCEDURE on Oracle PL/SQL with DECLARE variable

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I just currently learning about Oracle PL/SQL. I wanna create store procedure with variable and then call it with another script. Is it possible?

I tried use simple script without variable and it works:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE testmyproc AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO tes_table(dt)
VALUES (sysdate);
commit;
END testmyproc;
```

Then I call it with another script abc.sql

```
begin
  testmyproc;
end;
```

It works successfully.

But, unfortunately if I use DECLARE (variable) at my PROCEDURE, it show error when I execute (but it success in create procedure).

Here's my PROCEDURE (no error):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_testmyproc AS
DECLARE
   job_name varchar(100);
   status_key number;
   status_desc varchar(100);
   notes varchar(250);
BEGIN
    status_key := 1;
    status_desc := 'SUCCESS';
    notes := 'Process Completed';
    INSERT INTO automation_log(job_name, dt, status_key, status_desc, notes)
    VALUES (job_name, sysdate, status_key, status_desc, notes);
    commit;
END sp_testmyproc;
```

Here's my execure script abc.sql (show error when i execute it)

-without DECLARE

```
begin
  sp_testmyproc;
end;
```

-I tried to execute it with DECLARE

```
DECLARE
  job_name varchar(100);
  status_key number;
  status_desc varchar(100);
  notes varchar(250);
begin
  status_key := 1;
  status_desc := 'SUCCESS';
  notes := 'Process Completed';
  sp_testmyproc;
end;
```

It show error like this:

```
>     ORA-06550: line 8, column 11:
>     PLS-00905: SP_TESTMYPROC is invalid
>     ORA-06550: line 8, column 3:
>     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Can I call Procedure for another script? Is It best practice?
I just think PROCEDURE can be used for many cases (something like function in programming).

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to learn the syntax of the procedure.

In Procedure, You should not use the keyword `DECLARE`. Any variables you want to declare must be between `AS` and `BEGIN` in the procedure.

Your procedure should look like follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_testmyproc AS
--DECLARE
   job_name varchar(100);
   status_key number;
   status_desc varchar(100);
   notes varchar(250);
BEGIN
    status_key := 1;
    .....
    .....
    .....
```

Refer to this [document](https://www.oracletutorial.com/plsql-tutorial/plsql-procedure/) for the syntax of the oracle procedure as it is very easy to follow.

Comment: I have 2 PROCEDURE(s) to run like this,
when I change my PROCEDURE without DECLARE, the one execute successfully and the other still got same error.. Do you have any idea about error or this limitation?

Comment: I think it is altogether different issue. Mark it as accepted and ask othet question to avoid any mess in single question.

Answer (score 0):

Please note the difference when creating a stored procedure in SQL*Plus:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure test_ok as
  2   v number;
  3  begin
  4   v:=0;
  5  end;
  6  /

Procedure created.

SQL> show errors
No errors.


SQL> create or replace procedure test_ko as
  2  declare
  3   v number;
  4  begin
  5   v:=0;
  6  end;
  7  /

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

SQL> show errors
Errors for PROCEDURE TEST_KO:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
2/1  PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of
     the following:
     begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>
     <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete
     exists prior external language

SQL>
```

If you have compilation errors you get at least `Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.` If you have compilation errors and use `show errors` you get all error messages.

Comment: I run create PROCEDURE and execute it via PL/SQL Developer. Do I need use DECLARE or not to execute it?

Comment: You cannot use DECLARE in stored procedure: this does not depend on the client tool used. It depends only on PL/SQL that is running on the database server side.